# Only allow certain characters in a string

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, freepascal, lazarus

I am trying to validate a string, where by it can contain all alphebetical and numerical characters, aswell as the underline ( _ ) symbol.

This is what I tried so far:

```
var
  S: string;
const
  Allowed = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', '_'];
begin
  S := 'This_is_my_string_0123456789';

  if Length(S) > 0 then
  begin
    if (Pos(Allowed, S) > 0 then
      ShowMessage('Ok')
    else
      ShowMessage('string contains invalid symbols');
  end;
end;
```

In Lazarus this errors with:

> **Error:** Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Set Of Char", expected
>   "Variant"

Clearly my use of Pos is all wrong and I am not sure if my approach is even the correct way of going about it or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if `Pos` worked the way you wanted it to work (perhaps you want it to return the position of the first character in `S` that belongs to `Allowed`, which would be `1` in this case), the algorithm would not do what you want: it would say `Ok` if there is at least one allowed character in the string, and `string contains...` otherwise. Hence, it would say `Ok` for `⌬⌨∬∏⌫⌘B⌥` because this string does indeed contain an allowed character (`B`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to check every single character of the string, if it's contained in **Allowed**

e.g.:

```
var
  S: string;
const
  Allowed = ['A' .. 'Z', 'a' .. 'z', '0' .. '9', '_'];

  Function Valid: Boolean;
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    Result := Length(s) > 0;
    i := 1;
    while Result and (i <= Length(S)) do
    begin
      Result := Result AND (S[i] in Allowed);
      inc(i);
    end;
    if  Length(s) = 0 then Result := true;
  end;

begin
  S := 'This_is_my_string_0123456789';
  if Valid then
    ShowMessage('Ok')
  else
    ShowMessage('string contains invalid symbols');
end;
```

Comment: brilliant thanks, I just had a feeling I was doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
TYPE TCharSet = SET OF CHAR;

FUNCTION ValidString(CONST S : STRING ; CONST ValidChars : TCharSet) : BOOLEAN;
  VAR
    I : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    Result:=FALSE;
    FOR I:=1 TO LENGTH(S) DO IF NOT (S[I] IN ValidChars) THEN EXIT;
    Result:=TRUE
  END;
```

If you are using a Unicode version of Delphi (as you seem to be), beware that a SET OF CHAR cannot contain all valid characters in the Unicode character set. Then perhaps this function will be useful instead:

```
FUNCTION ValidString(CONST S,ValidChars : STRING) : BOOLEAN;
  VAR
    I : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    Result:=FALSE;
    FOR I:=1 TO LENGTH(S) DO IF POS(S[I],ValidChars)=0 THEN EXIT;
    Result:=TRUE
  END;
```

but then again, not all characters (actually Codepoints) in Unicode can be expressed by a single character, and some characters can be expressed in more than one way (both as a single character and as a multi-character).

But as long as you constrain yourself within these limitations, one of the above functions should be useful. You can even include both, if you add an "OVERLOAD;" directive to the end of each function declaration, as in:

```
FUNCTION ValidString(CONST S : STRING ; CONST ValidChars : TCharSet) : BOOLEAN; OVERLOAD;
FUNCTION ValidString(CONST S,ValidChars : STRING) : BOOLEAN; OVERLOAD;
```

Comment: I think you left your caps lock on! :)

Comment: No - if I had done that, I would have typed something like FUNCTION vALIDsTRING(CONST S : STRING ; CONST vALIDcHARS : tcHARsET) : BOOLEAN; I didn't, so one must assume that what I wrote was what I intended...

Comment: I think I said it because it does not following a general coding style. If I used this code the first thing I would do is make it all lowercase. Please don't take this as an insult or anything, it's just I think all or most code should follow the same style. Regardless of that, I appreciate your answer thanks.

Comment: You have your way of writing code, I have mine. If you use my code, I would expect you to reformat it to follow your own convention, just like I would reformat any code of yours that I might use. Criticizing (or even commenting on) another person's coding style is analogous to criticizing/commenting on people's spelling. If the code is understandable and compilable, then it is good code, no matter how it is written. I don't comment on other people's lack of proper punctuation and/or spelling and/or misuse of "your" vs. "you're", "there" vs. "their" and so on, unless it alters the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Lazarus/Free Pascal doesn't overload pos for that but has "posset" variants in unit strutils for that;

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/posset.html

Regarding Andreas' (IMHO correct ) remark, you can use isemptystr for that. It was meant to check for strings that only contain whitespace, but it basically checks if a string only contains characters in a set.

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/isemptystr.html

Comment: No. To use `PosSet` you would have to build a set of invalid chars instead of valid (which is insane to do and would surely exceed the set limits).

Comment: True, which is why I mentioned isemptystr, but probably my update crossed with your post. My point was more that there are predefined routines for both cases.

Comment: Yes, `IsEmptyStr` is the way, although this would be a line of code that should have been commented (because it would look on the first view that the code writer is going to check if the string is empty). But anyway, I don't think there's a similar function in Delphi... [+1]

Comment: Report a bug/QC for Delphi  :_)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions:

```
uses System.RegularExpressions;


if not TRegEx.IsMatch(S, '^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+$') then
  ShowMessage('string contains invalid symbols');
```